# Glyphicons changing size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm trying to arrange some glyphicons on a webpage that will eventually contain links when clicked. I want them to change colour when the cursor touches them but cannot figure out why in my current attempt they all seem to change size so much. (I don't mind them changing size a little). Please see fiddle. http://www.bootply.com/Z8TAzgPwLb

Comment: You're adding a padding on hover... And another thing ids should be only used once on a pageload, so pls don't use `id="glyphicon"` on every one of them. that's not valid html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `padding` you are modifying the size of the element in its hover state. Correct the offset by setting its relative position:

```
#glyphicon:hover, .glyphicon:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #808080;
    padding: 20px;
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
}
```

This should get you going. You would still need to correct the position of your `<h4>` element, in parallel to the above.

Comment: This will still push the text down. If you use `position: relative;` still the original space is occupied.

Comment: @Pinki: yes, see my last paragraph.

Comment: @knittl this still makes the div around it bigger. I don't think this is a good aproach, the part under it has to be repainted by the browser just to add a padding? Why don't you add the passing before the hover and then only change the backgroundcolor and the color?

Comment: @Pinki: you can always provide your own answer, if you have a different solution which you think solves the problem better. I provided mine, pointed out the caveat of it.

Comment: I did write what my solution would be... but instead of padding i wrote passing...